# "onChange" Problem on Google Chrome Version 71.0.3573.0

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onchange

There is a problem with 'onChange' property on google chrome version 71.0.3573.0

Simple example that works on former versions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="cars" onchange="func()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
function func() {
  alert('chrome 71.0.3573.0 does not get here');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried this one with JavaScript, which doen't work too:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById("cars").setAttribute("onChange", "func()");
function func() {
  alert('chrome 71.0.3573.0 does not get here');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This problem is probably with that specific Chrome version, as I have tried running that code on another computer with the same version, unsuccessfully. Any suggestions how to solve that (except download another version)? Thanks.

Comment: How about asking Google Chrome Support?

Comment: You should not use `onchange="func()"`  or `.setAttribute("onChange", "func()")` to attach event listeners. Write either `document.getElementById("cars").onchange = func` or `document.getElementById("cars").addEventListener('change', func, false)`

Comment: Thanks @t.niese, it solves the problem. Yet the 'onchange' as a property doesn't work, so I sent a message to Google Chrome Support about that.